# SELECTING from a UNION GETTING A JOIN ISSUE

Tags: sql-server, join, union

I am trying to run the below query that would basically pull three columns from a two query `UNION`- I am getting the error that the multi-part identifier H.po_number on line 1 could not be bound.  I know that is a `JOIN` issue but not sure why?  The query runs perfectly on its own but when I add the first `SELECT` I get the `JOIN` issue.  This is actually going to be in an `INSERT` statement that pulls those first three values out and stores in another table for error tracking.  Any idea why that breaks it? Its format sucks right now - working on that part (captial and lowercase, etc.)

```
select H.po_number as [sap po number],
       getdate(),
      'sapnotgps' as [report_source]

from   

    (SELECT * FROM ( SELECT S.team_member_name as [ASSIGNED EMPLOYEE], -- Using NEW employee table
    H.po_type as [PO TYPE],
    G.order_no as [GPS PO #],
    H.po_number as [SAP PO NUMBER],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),H.po_issue_date,101) AS [PO ISSUE DATE],
    M.department      as [DEPARTMENT],
    K.business_unit_desc  as [BU],
    M.description     as [DESCRIPTION],
    M.material        as [MATERIAL],
    H.po_ordered_quantity as [PO QUANTITY],-- Use header ordered qty to negate multi-line po issue (do not SUM!)
    MAX(P.comment) as [PO COMMENT],
    MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),E.[date],101)) as [FIRST SHOWN ON RPT]


from (
  select order_no, order_status, cst_order_no, status_date,last_conf_date_cst
  from asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder1
  union all
  select order_no, order_status, cst_order_no, status_date,last_conf_date_cst
  from asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder2
  union all
  select order_no, order_status, cst_order_no, status_date,last_conf_date_cst
  from asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder3
  ) G
  join pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_header H
    on G.order_no = H.ahag_number
  join pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_item P
    on H.po_number = P.po_number
  join pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_mm_material M 
    on P.material = M.material
  join pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_kd_business_unit K 
    on M.business_unit_code = K.business_unit_code
  join adi_user_maintained.dbo.scm_po_employee_name S 
    on S.po_number = P.po_number
  join adi_user_maintained.dbo.scm_po_error_tracking E 
    on H.po_number = E.po_number 

  where G.order_status <> '90' 
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_item i
    where i.po_number = H.po_number
      and (i.del_indicator <> 'L' or i.del_indicator is null
      and M.business_segment_code not in ('421','420','422','424'))) --exclude adi golf

    group by G.order_no,
             G.last_conf_date_cst,
             H.po_number,
         H.po_issue_date,
             M.material,
             M.[description],
             K.business_unit_desc,
             M.department,
             H.po_created_by,
             S.team_member_name,
             H.po_type,
             H.po_ordered_quantity
       ) AS C

UNION ALL 

    (SELECT 

       S.team_member_name AS [ASSIGNED EMPLOYEE],
       H.po_type AS [PO TYPE],
       G.order_no AS [GPS PO #], 
       H.po_number AS [SAP PO NUMBER],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),H.po_issue_date,101) AS [PO ISSUE DATE],
       M.department AS [DEPARTMENT],
       K.business_unit_desc AS [BU],
       M.[description] AS [DESCRIPTION],
       P.material AS [MATERIAL], 
       P.po_ordered_quantity AS [PO QUANTITY],
       P.comment AS [PO COMMENT],
       MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),E.[date],101)) AS [FIRST SHOWN ON RPT]

FROM   pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_header H 
JOIN   pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_item P 
ON     H.po_number = P.po_number 
JOIN   pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_mm_material M
ON     P.material = M.material 
JOIN   pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_kd_business_unit K
ON     M.business_unit_code = K.business_unit_code 
JOIN   adi_user_maintained.dbo.scm_po_employee_name S 
ON     H.po_number = S.po_number
JOIN   adi_user_maintained.dbo.scm_po_error_tracking E 
ON     H.po_number = E.po_number 
JOIN  
(SELECT order_no, 
        order_status, 
        status_date,
        right(cst_order_no,10) as [cst_order_no_10],
        last_conf_date_cst,
        cst_order_no

FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder1

UNION ALL

SELECT    order_no, 
          order_status, 
          status_date,
          right(cst_order_no,10) as [cst_order_no_10],
          last_conf_date_cst,
          cst_order_no

FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder2

UNION ALL 

SELECT    order_no, 
          order_status, 
          status_date,
          right(cst_order_no,10) as [cst_order_no_10],
          last_conf_date_cst,
          cst_order_no

FROM   asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder3) G 
ON     P.po_number = G.cst_order_no_10

WHERE  H.ahag_number LIKE '0%'

AND    G.order_status <> '90'

AND NOT EXISTS  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_item i
    WHERE i.po_number = H.po_number
      AND (i.del_indicator <> 'L' or i.del_indicator IS NULL --find ONLY PO's where all lines are L
      AND M.business_segment_code NOT IN ('421','420','422','424'))) --exclude adi golf

GROUP BY S.team_member_name,
         H.po_type,
         G.order_no, 
         H.po_number,
         H.po_issue_date,
         G.last_conf_date_cst,
         M.department,
         K.business_unit_desc,
         M.[description],
         P.material, 
         P.po_ordered_quantity,
         P.comment)) AS D;
```

Comment: `H.po_number as [SAP PO NUMBER]` which means you should try `[SAP PO NUMBER]` instead of `H.po_number` on your first line.

Answer (score 0):

The alias h has "expired" (and replaced by the alias "d") in the topmost select clause. Additionally all the column aliases you have used through the subqueries are also now active. So your final select should look more like this:

```
SELECT
      GETDATE()
    , 'sapnotgps' AS [report_source]
    , d.[assigned employee]
    , d.[po type]
    , d.[gps po #]
    , d.[sap po number]
    , d.[po issue date]
    , d.[department]
    , d.[bu]
    , d.[description]
    , d.[material]
    , d.[po quantity]
    , d.[po comment]
    , d.[first shown on rpt]
```

or without the alias d:

```
SELECT
      GETDATE()
    , 'sapnotgps' AS [report_source]
    , [assigned employee]
    , [po type]
    , [gps po #]
    , [sap po number]
    , [po issue date]
    , [department]
    , [bu]
    , [description]
    , [material]
    , [po quantity]
    , [po comment]
    , [first shown on rpt]
FROM (
      SELECT
            *
      FROM (
            SELECT
                  s.team_member_name                         AS [assigned employee]
                 -- Using NEW employee table
                , h.po_type                                  AS [po type]
                , g.order_no                                 AS [gps po #]
                , h.po_number                                AS [sap po number]
                , CONVERT(varchar(12), h.po_issue_date, 101) AS [po issue date]
                , m.department                               AS [department]
                , k.business_unit_desc                       AS [bu]
                , m.description                              AS [description]
                , m.material                                 AS [material]
                , h.po_ordered_quantity                      AS [po quantity]
                -- Use header ordered qty to negate multi-line po issue (do not SUM!)
                , MAX(p.comment)                             AS [po comment]
                , MIN(CONVERT(varchar(12), e.[date], 101))   AS [first shown on rpt]


            FROM (
                  SELECT
                        order_no
                      , order_status
                      , cst_order_no
                      , status_date
                      , last_conf_date_cst
                  FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder1
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT
                        order_no
                      , order_status
                      , cst_order_no
                      , status_date
                      , last_conf_date_cst
                  FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder2
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT
                        order_no
                      , order_status
                      , cst_order_no
                      , status_date
                      , last_conf_date_cst
                  FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder3
            ) g
            JOIN pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_header h ON g.order_no = h.ahag_number
            JOIN pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_item p ON h.po_number = p.po_number
            JOIN pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_mm_material m ON p.material = m.material
            JOIN pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_kd_business_unit k ON m.business_unit_code = k.business_unit_code
            JOIN adi_user_maintained.dbo.scm_po_employee_name s ON s.po_number = p.po_number
            JOIN adi_user_maintained.dbo.scm_po_error_tracking e ON h.po_number = e.po_number

            WHERE g.order_status <> '90'
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT
                        1
                  FROM pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_item i
                  WHERE i.po_number = h.po_number
                  AND (i.del_indicator <> 'L'
                  OR i.del_indicator IS NULL
                  AND m.business_segment_code NOT IN ('421', '420', '422', '424'))
            ) --exclude adi golf

            GROUP BY
                  g.order_no
                , g.last_conf_date_cst
                , h.po_number
                , h.po_issue_date
                , m.material
                , m.[description]
                , k.business_unit_desc
                , m.department
                , h.po_created_by
                , s.team_member_name
                , h.po_type
                , h.po_ordered_quantity
      ) AS c

      UNION ALL

      (SELECT

            s.team_member_name                         AS [assigned employee]
          , h.po_type                                  AS [po type]
          , g.order_no                                 AS [gps po #]
          , h.po_number                                AS [sap po number]
          , CONVERT(varchar(12), h.po_issue_date, 101) AS [po issue date]
          , m.department                               AS [department]
          , k.business_unit_desc                       AS [bu]
          , m.[description]                            AS [description]
          , p.material                                 AS [material]
          , p.po_ordered_quantity                      AS [po quantity]
          , p.comment                                  AS [po comment]
          , MIN(CONVERT(varchar(12), e.[date], 101))   AS [first shown on rpt]

      FROM pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_header h
      JOIN pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_item p ON h.po_number = p.po_number
      JOIN pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_mm_material m ON p.material = m.material
      JOIN pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_kd_business_unit k ON m.business_unit_code = k.business_unit_code
      JOIN adi_user_maintained.dbo.scm_po_employee_name s ON h.po_number = s.po_number
      JOIN adi_user_maintained.dbo.scm_po_error_tracking e ON h.po_number = e.po_number
      JOIN (
            SELECT
                  order_no
                , order_status
                , status_date
                , RIGHT(cst_order_no, 10) AS [cst_order_no_10]
                , last_conf_date_cst
                , cst_order_no

            FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder1

            UNION ALL

            SELECT
                  order_no
                , order_status
                , status_date
                , RIGHT(cst_order_no, 10) AS [cst_order_no_10]
                , last_conf_date_cst
                , cst_order_no

            FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder2

            UNION ALL

            SELECT
                  order_no
                , order_status
                , status_date
                , RIGHT(cst_order_no, 10) AS [cst_order_no_10]
                , last_conf_date_cst
                , cst_order_no

            FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder3
      ) g ON p.po_number = g.cst_order_no_10

      WHERE h.ahag_number LIKE '0%'

      AND g.order_status <> '90'

      AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                  1
            FROM pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_item i
            WHERE i.po_number = h.po_number
            AND (i.del_indicator <> 'L'
            OR i.del_indicator IS NULL --find ONLY PO's where all lines are L
            AND m.business_segment_code NOT IN ('421', '420', '422', '424'))
      ) --exclude adi golf

      GROUP BY
            s.team_member_name
          , h.po_type
          , g.order_no
          , h.po_number
          , h.po_issue_date
          , g.last_conf_date_cst
          , m.department
          , k.business_unit_desc
          , m.[description]
          , p.material
          , p.po_ordered_quantity
          , p.comment)
) AS d;
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
select H.po_number as [sap po number],
       getdate(),
      'sapnotgps' as [report_source]
```

with

```
select D.[SAP PO NUMBER],
       getdate(),
      'sapnotgps' as [report_source]
```

Thanks.